# PowerShell: What exactly is $input inside Start-Job?

Tags: powershell, windows-8.1, powershell-4.0

Consider the following code. I am simply passing in an array of 32-bit, signed integers `[Int32[]]` into the `Start-Job` cmdlet, by using the `-InputObject` parameter.

```
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { $input.GetType().FullName; } -InputObject @(1,2,3);
Wait-Job -Job $Job;
Receive-Job -Keep $Job;
```

The result of this code is:

```
System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineReader`1+<GetReadEnumerator>d__0[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

Looking at the documentation for the [PipelineReader .NET class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms551699%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it has a `ReadToEnd()` method. Therefore, the following code ought to work:

```
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { $input.ReadToEnd(); } -InputObject @(1,2,3);
Wait-Job -Job $Job;
Receive-Job -Keep $Job;
```

But instead, I get an error message:

> Method invocation failed because [System.Int32] does not contain a method named 'ReadToEnd'.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
>       + PSComputerName        : localhost

So then I think, I'll just use the `PSBase` property to get the "real" object.

```
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { $input.psbase.ReadToEnd(); } -InputObject @(1,2,3);
Wait-Job -Job $Job;
Receive-Job -Keep $Job;
```

But then I get a similar error message:

> Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSInternalMemberSet] does not contain a method named 'ReadToEnd'.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ReadToEnd:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
>       + PSComputerName        : localhost

I noticed that there is a [Microsoft Connect bug filed](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/541852/getreadenumerator-d-0-4-this-read-by-design) around this confusion, but it confuses me even more. Apparently the `PipelineReader` class has a confusingly-named property `<>4__this`, which has a `Read()` method, which you can't actually see by using `Get-Member`.

**Bottom line**: Does anyone know how to simply "unwrap" the contents of the `$input` automatic variable, when input is submitted via the `-InputObject` parameter on the `Start-Job` cmdlet, so that I can work with the objects on an individual basis?

This script should simply return `1`, not `1, 2, 3`.

```
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { $input[0]; } -InputObject @(1,2,3);
Wait-Job -Job $Job;
Receive-Job -Keep $Job;
```

Comment: Would `$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { $($input)[0]; } -InputObject @(1,2,3)` work for you?

Comment: Yes, but can you further explain what `$input` is? That's what I'm ultimately trying to understand.

Comment: I think I have a better example. [about_Automatic_Variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) indicates `$input` in an enumerator, which you cannot index like an array.  Try this: `$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { $input.getEnumerator()[0] } -InputObject @(1,2,3)`

Comment: pwsh continues to boggle.  I can't say I love anything about this, but my workaround is to do something like `Start-Job -Name $name -ScriptBlock { $_argv = $input|%{$_}; $_argv[0], $_argv[1] | Write-Host } -InputObject @('arg1', 'arg2')`.  I was having problems because I though `-InputObject` meant I could, say, pass a Hashtable (I guess you still can, but the results won't not drive you nuts).  Should be called `-InputArray` or `-InputEnumerable` or something to indicate that you can't really pass an "object".

Answer (score 5):

Presumably `$input` is an enumerator, just like in a standard pipeline.
In order to process items we should either use a `process` block with the
automatic variable `$_` or pass `$input` in another pipeline in an`end`
block (implicit if not specified).

```
# process each item separately
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {process{$_}} -InputObject @(1,2,3);
Wait-Job -Job $Job;
Receive-Job -Keep $Job;

# process the whole $input
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {$input | %{$_}} -InputObject @(1,2,3);
Wait-Job -Job $Job;
Receive-Job -Keep $Job;

# compare with script blocks in standard pipelines

# each item
@(1,2,3) | . {process{$_}}

# whole input
@(1,2,3) | . {$input | %{$_}}
```

Perhaps there are other ways to enumerate items of `$input` but they are
not often used in practice, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> $Input
>    Contains an enumerator that enumerates all input that is passed to a
>    function. The $input variable is available only to functions and script
>    blocks (which are unnamed functions).  In the Process block of a
>    function, the $input variable enumerates the object that is currently
>    in the pipeline. When the Process block  completes, there are no objects
>    left in the pipeline, so the $input variable enumerates an empty
>    collection. If the function does not have a Process block, then in the
>    End block, the $input variable enumerates the collection of all input to
>    the function.
> ```

Source: [about_Automatic_Variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx)

To sum up: `$input` is an automatic variable that contains the WHOLE pipeline in the form of an enumerator, unlike `$_` which is the "the current object" in the pipeline.

Here's an example of how to use it.

```
function test {
    #$input is an enumerator that you should use $input | foreach-object { } to access the objects.

    #To to get all items you could e.g. convert the enumerator to an array.
    $arr = @($input)

    #If you need to use the $input enumerator for something else, you need to call .Reset() first as the enumerator has reached the end.
    $input.Reset()

    #Print some values from the data
    $arr.count
    $arr[0]
}

PS> "hello", "world" | test


2
hello
```

**UPDATE**: Here's the proof that this also applies to you `Start-Job` scenario. The samples are commented to explain.

```
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { 
    #Read the complete pipeline to an array
    $data= @($input)
    "`$data is an $($data.GetType().Name) with $($data.count) objects"

    #Unlike in a pipeline, where the `Start-Job` command would be called once per object like `Start-Job ...... -InputObject $_`, 
    #you're inputing a single `object[]` object the the pipeline. So you only have one item in your $input pipeline.

    #Get our inputobject (our array)
    $arr= $data[0]
    "`$arr is an $($arr.GetType().Name)"

    #Use array
    "$($arr[0]) is less than $($arr[1]) which is less than $($arr[2])"
} -InputObject @(1,2,3);

Wait-Job -Job $Job;
Receive-Job -Keep $Job;

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
54     Job54           BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost             ...                     
$data is an Object[] with 1 objects
$arr is an ArrayList
1 is less then 2 which is less then 3
```

And to prove my "theory" about the pipeline. Here's the pipelined version:

```
$Job = 1, 2, 3 | Start-Job -ScriptBlock { 
    #Read the complete pipeline to an array
    $data= @($input)
    "`$data is an $($data.GetType().Name) with $($data.count) objects"

    #Now the command is run per object, so the $input enumerator contained our 3 seperate Int32 values.

    #Get a single object in the pipeline
    $OneOfTheValues= $data[0]
    "`$OneOfTheValues is an $($OneOfTheValues.GetType().Name)"

    #Use data
    "$($data[0]) is less than $($data[1]) which is less than $($data[2])"
}

Wait-Job -Job $Job;
Receive-Job -Keep $Job;

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
58     Job58           BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost             ...                     
$data is an Object[] with 3 objects
$OneOfTheValues is an Int32
1 is less then 2 which is less then 3
```

So I stand by my original answer. The behavior is equal, you're simply using the pipeline/cmdlet in a different way. :)

Comment: `Start-Job` does not behave this way. See my examples.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
$Job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { $input.movenext();$input.current[0] } -InputObject @(1,2,3);
Wait-Job -Job $Job;
Receive-Job -Keep $Job;
```